# build_absolute_uri in Django admin (for a list_display field)

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm trying to display an absolute URI in the list display of a Django admin:

```
from django.contrib import admin
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = (
        'full_uri',
    )

    readonly_fields = (
        'full_uri',
    )

    def full_uri(self, obj):
        return u'<a href="{url}">{url}'.format(
            url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('view_name', args=(obj.pk, )))
        )
    full_uri.allow_tags = True
```

The problem - I don't have access to the request object (in which `build_absolute_uri` is defined).

I tried to override `changelist_view` and store request localy, but this is not [thread safe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3388173/1705056).

I also tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8817935/1705056) solution, but it's not very elegant.

Any other ideas?

**EDIT:**

Is this a safe solution:

```
def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    self.request = request
    try:
        return super(MyAdmin,self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)
    finally:
        self.request = None
```

**EDIT2:**

Not thread-safe at all! [1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6887028/1705056) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764685/django-modeladmin-with-request-user-based-restrictions-on-the-fieldsets-needs-t), ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found a way to do it in a thread-safe manner, create a function inside `get_list_display`:

```
def get_list_display(self, request):

   def link_to_view(obj):
        return u'<a href="{url}">{url}'.format(
            url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('view_name', args=(obj, )))
        )
    token_access_link.short_description = _('link')
    token_access_link.allow_tags = True

    return (
        link_to_view,
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

Every class that extends admin.ModelAdmin comes with two functions you can override: change_view, and changelist_view.  `change_view` is called when you edit a single instance, `changelist_view` is called when viewing the list of all items.

Those two functionas act as the view definition for the admin and contain the request object for the page.  This means that within those two function, you could store the request as a property of `self` to make it accessible to other functions within the class called from that view.  With that, being said, something like this should work:

```
from django.contrib import admin
class MyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
list_display = (
    'full_uri',
)

readonly_fields = (
    'full_uri',
)

def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    # access the request object when in the change view
    self.request = request
    return super(MyAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url=form_url, extra_context=extra_context)

def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
    # access the request object when in the list view
    self.request = request
    return super(MyAdmin,self).changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)

def full_uri(self, obj):
    return u'<a href="{url}">{url}'.format(
        # access the request object through self.request, as set by the two view functions
        url = self.request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('view_name', args=(obj.pk, )))
    )
full_uri.allow_tags = True
```

Comment: well, I guess that if we surround this with `try-finally` it might be OK to do so.

Comment: I'm not sure why you would need to wrap the call to super in a try.  I've never done that before.

Comment: Since ModelAdmin instances are used by different requests, it's not recommended to change their status. The finally is to ensure that cleanup happens no matter what.

Comment: Sorry. After digging further, I have to unaccept your answer as it is really thread-unsafe. I think I found a way to do it though..

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood the question correctly, you just need access to the request object in a function that hasn't been sent it?

If so, I've found [django-globals](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-globals) to be the most helpful as it provides universal access to the current request and user (which should be accessible by default like in flask!)

```
pip install django-globals
```

settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
   ...
   'django_globals'
]
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
    ...
    'django_globals.middleware.Global'
]
```

view.py

```
from django_globals import globals as djglobals

def myfunc():
    djglobals.user
    djglobals.request
```